# CORS request failed between containerized React and C# applications

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, cors

Running the React application locally with my .Net application running on Docker seems to work fine, but running both with `docker-compose` results in CORS failures:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend:5000/Account/Login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://backend:5000/
```

React `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /user/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

and .Net `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/MyApplicationName/MyApplicationName.Api
RUN dotnet build .
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet run --urls "http://*:5000;http://*:5001" MyApplicationName.Api.dll
```

I've done a bit of searching and have added the following to `Startup.cs` as well but it hasn't changed anything:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(_allowedOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true).AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(_allowedOrigins);

            ...
        }
```

Comment: The *“CORS request did not succeed”* error message actually indicates the problem is something other than CORS-related. I literally means the browser failed to successfully complete the request. Or in other words, it means the transaction never reached the point of the server actually responding. So it can often indicate a failure at the network level, not at the server level. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

Comment: That explains it, thanks a lot. I'll double-check the schemes I'm using and try it on other browsers without ad blockers

Answer (score 0):

> Note: For security reasons, specifics about what went wrong with a
> CORS request are not available to JavaScript code. All the code knows
> is that an error occurred. The only way to determine what specifically
> went wrong is to look at the browser's console for details.
>
> CORS error messages Firefox's console displays messages in its console
> when requests fail due to CORS. Part of the error text is a "reason"
> message that provides added insight into what went wrong. The reason
> messages are listed below; click the message to open an article
> explaining the error in more detail and offering possible solutions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

You could do the same in Chrome.

But I would first start with a less restrictive CORS policy in the container to see if that works.

BTW, are you behind a corporate proxy?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your CORS policy on the server allows any method, and allows any header (if using authentication):

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
                app.UseCors(builder => {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                });

            // etc...
        }
```

**IMPORTANT:** The above configuration is, in most cases, fine for development, but it is necessary to carefully evaluate whether the above will be safe for production, as it allows any browser-based application can call your API.